# Building PHP 8.1.8 with open SSL, failing unable to find package. Lambda Layer

Tags: php, configuration, openssl, amazon-lambda

I'm trying to build a PHP8.1.8 lambda layer however i was following https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/apn/aws-lambda-custom-runtime-for-php-a-practical-example/

And just using the correct version, so the first thing I did was spin up a Node.JS Lambda in the console and output the process.versions, to identify the correct version of OpenSSL to use that reported `openssl: '1.1.1n+quic'` so i changed the example they give to

```bash
curl -sL https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.1.1q.tar.gz | tar -xvz
cd openssl-1.1.1q
./config && make && sudo make install
cd ~
```

And this seemingly worked, other than when i ran `openssl version` i was getting an error about missing libssl.so.1.1 so i ran

```bash
sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib64/libssl.so.1.1 /usr/lib64/libssl.so.1.1
sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib64/libcrypto.so.1.1 /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.1.1
```

and if i now run `openssl version` i get correctly reporting `1.1.1q`

I then again changed the script from the blog to use PHP8.1.8 instead of 7 stuff and ran the below without any problem

```bash
mkdir ~/php-8-bin
curl -sL https://www.php.net/distributions/php-8.1.8.tar.gz | tar -xvz
cd php-8.1.8

./buildconf --force
```

however my problem is when i try and run `./configure --prefix=/home/ec2-user/php-8-bin/ --with-openssl=/usr/local/ssl --with-curl --with-zlib` i get error `No package 'openssl' found` and i have absolutely no idea how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a couple of hours and talking in the #linux channel in the Libera IRC how to fix this is when building PHP to override the PKG_CONFIG_PATH to include the lib64 dir.

```bash
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib64/pkgconfig:${PKG_CONFIG_PATH} ./configure --prefix=/home/ec2-user/php-8-bin --with-curl --with-zlib
```